# getopts not parsing args properly

Tags: bash, getopt, getopts

Here is my short script:

```
#!/bin/bash
user=""
secret=""
pkgname=""

while getopts ":p:s:u:" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
        p )
        pkgname=$OPTARG
        echo "p=$pkgname"
     ;;
      s )
      secret=$OPTARG
        echo "s=$secret"
      ;;
   u )
      user=$OPTARG
        echo "u=$user"
      ;;
   \? )
        usage
        exit 1
      ;;
    :)
    echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument."
    usage
    exit 1
  esac
done
```

When I run it using following command:

```
./script.sh -u 'uuuu' -s 'aaaa' -p pkg.rpm
```

Output:

```
u=uuuu
s=aaaa -p
```

While I expect it to be

```
u=uuuu
s=aaaa
p=pkg.rpm
```

I tried doing multiple combinations of the parameters by changing the sequence as well but not able to solve it.
Why the value for 's' is incorrect?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, your script works as intended for me.

Comment: Works for me.  It appears you have a control character before the -p which the CLI parser is not recognized as space.  Update your echo link with 'echo "u=$user" | cat -v' The -v on cat will displace non visible control characters.

Comment: Yes there was a ctrl character. Removing it solved the problem. Thanks a lot @WaltDe .